# How do I return function value in lifecycle-aware coroutine scope in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle, kotlin-coroutines

```
fun returnValue(): Int {
    viewModelScope.launch { 
        return 1 // Something like this
    }
}
```

I want to return some value in a viewModelScope like the above. I don't want my function to be suspended function. How do I achieve that?

Comment: What does it mean "return some value in a viewModelScope"? Why doesn't your function simply `return 1` without involving any `launch`?

Comment: You can use a livedatascope to return a livedata which can be observed in your activity/fragment class

Comment: My guess is you want to have your cake and eat it, too. Not block the calling thread, but also return the value right from this function. You can't do it. You have to do the suspendable, non-blocking computation within `launch` and also use the result of that computation from within the `launch` block. This means the callback you have this in will complete before you see the result, and your application must live with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `returnValue()` cannot be suspended function, there are basically only two options:

1. Turn the return type into `Deferred<Int>` and make the caller responsible for handling the return value at a later point. The body becomes:

```kotlin
fun returnValue(): Deferred<Int> = viewModelScope.async {
    return@async 1
}
```

2. Block the thread until the value is available:

```kotlin
fun returnValue(): Int {
    return runBlocking(viewModelScope.coroutineContext) {
        return@runBlocking 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
suspend fun returnValue(): Int {
    suspendCoroutine<Int> { cont ->
        viewModelScope.launch {
            cont.resume(1)
        }
    }
}
```